# How to change Discord.py button color and disable on interaction

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to change the button color to grey and disable it once it is clicked but nothing I find seems to be working. It really seems like it should be simple enough to do and I tried 'edit_message' but maybe I used it wrong. Here is the code for my button, I took out all the irrelevant code.

I really appreciate any help you can offer.
Thanks!

```py
    @discord.ui.button(label="Daily Game", style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple)
    async def daily_fantasy(self, interaction:discord.Interaction, 
                            button:discord.ui.Button):

        await interaction.response.send_message(content=f"Let's get started!", 
                                                ephemeral=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the button using the [`disabled`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.ui.Button.disabled) property. And changing the style using the [`style`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.ui.Button.style) property.

```py
@discord.ui.button(label="Daily Game", style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple)
async def daily_fantasy(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
    button.disabled = True
    button.style = discord.ButtonStyle.grey
    await interaction.response.edit_message(view=self)
    await interaction.followup.send(content=f"Let's get started!", ephemeral=True)
```

Comment: I actually keep getting the same error as before... "discord.errors.InteractionResponded: This interaction has already been responded to before"

Comment: Are you using the `response` more than once? I deliberately used `interaction.followup.send` for the subsequent message. An interaction can only be responded to once (hence the error) so you have to use the `followup` WebHook object or use `interaction.channel.send` or something to send instead.

Comment: You're right again.. sorry about that. I missed the followup.send. Thanks

Comment: No worries - glad it worked and to have helped :) easy to get caught off guard with response/followup!